# Solve nonlinear matrix equations for vibration problem

Tags: matrix-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to write a program to calculate the steady state response of a beam structure to harmonic loading. The system is damped not only by 'structural damping' (which is linear) but also by air resistance (which is nonlinear, and calculated using $F_{li}=-\frac{1}{2}\rho A_i C_{Di}u_{li}|u_{li}|$... the minus sign and absolute value resulting in an air resistance force that acts to oppose the motion of the beam). Although the air resistance doesn't vary sinusoidally when the motion is sinusoidal, it isn't far off so I want to represent it as a harmonic force acting to oppose the loading force.

I have the mass and stiffness matrices for the beam ($\boldsymbol{[M]}$ and $\boldsymbol{[K]}$) and so I am able to obtain the eigenvectors and eigenvalues ($\boldsymbol{[V]}$ and $\boldsymbol{[D]}$). The eigenvalues yields a vector containing the natural frequencies of the system (the square root of the diagonal entries of $\boldsymbol{[D]}$, I'll call it $\boldsymbol{\omega}$.

The system is excited by a force vector in the global reference frame $\boldsymbol{F_0}$ at an excitation frequency $\omega_F$.

There is a rotation matrix which rotates the beams from the local to the global reference frame $\boldsymbol{[R]}$.

I have successfully used the procedure to calculate the steady state response without aerodynamic damping:

- Get eigenvalues and eigenvectors $\boldsymbol{[V]}$ and $\boldsymbol{[D]}$
- Get generalised force vector $\boldsymbol{Q}=\boldsymbol{[V]}^T \boldsymbol{F_0}$
- Calculate modal participation factor vector $\boldsymbol{q}$. The individual elements are calculated as follows:

$$q_i=\frac{Q_i}{{\omega_i}^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{[(1-(\omega_F/\omega_i)^2)^2+(2\zeta_i\omega_F/\omega_i)^2]}}$$

- We can but the elements of $\boldsymbol{q}$ without the scaling given by $\boldsymbol{Q}$ on the diagonal of a matrix $\boldsymbol{[A]}$, which I'll use later.
- Calculate response from $\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{[V]q}$

The problem is that in the aerodynamic forcing equation above, $u_i$ (the nodal velocity in the local reference frame) is dependent on $\boldsymbol{x}$, which is calculated as $\boldsymbol{u_l}=\omega\boldsymbol{[R]^Tx}$ so the equation cannot be solved directly for $\boldsymbol{x}$.

I've tried solving it by using Newton-Raphson iterations but I've not had much luck... for some reason it works when the beams are lying in the original reference plane but as soon as  $\boldsymbol{[R]}$ is anything other than identity it stops working. Does anyone have any pointers on how how to solve this:

$$\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{[V][A][V]^TF_0+[V][A][V]^TF_d}$$

where

$$\boldsymbol{F_d}=\boldsymbol{[R]F_l}$$

The components of $\boldsymbol{F_l}$ are calculated from $F_{li}=-\frac{1}{2}\rho A_i C_{Di}u_{li}|u_{li}|$ in which $\boldsymbol{u_l}=\omega\boldsymbol{[R]^Tx}$.

Any help will be very much appreciated... although even if I don't get any I've definitely improved my Tex skills!

Comment: A useful trick is to linearize $\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}'-\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{x}'$ where $\mathbf{x}'$ is the value of $\mathbf{x}$ from the previous iteration. However, I suspect that this is nothing but a specialization of the Newton-Raphson method.

Comment: The air resistance formula holds in the global coordinate system. Perhaps you transform too much or forget to transform back. I'd expect the linearized damped system to still have symmetric matrices, including a damping matrix dependent on $\mathbf{x}'$.

Comment: The $u_{li}$ seem to be *velocities*, sort of $\dot{\mathbf{x}}$, right?

Comment: $\boldsymbol{u_{li}}$ is indeed velocities... I didn't know how to do a dot above an x so I made up a new symbol. I've just been looking into doing this with an "equivalent aerodynamic damping ratio", but this still requires knowledge of $\boldsymbol{x}$ so I don't know if it will help.

Comment: Your $\omega$ should be complex. Is the $\mathrm{i}$ included or not? An error there would carry over to $F_{li}$.

Comment: Why should $\omega$ be complex? The i is just a subscript for the position in the vector. There was no mention of complex stuff in the book I got the steady state calculation from.

Comment: Seems to be the extra $\mathbf{R}$ for $\mathbf{F}_d$ to me. The system mass matrix and stiffness matrix should be expressed relative to the global coordinate system. Then $\mathbf{x}$ is in global coordinates already, and all $\mathbf{F}$ are expected to be in global coords as well. Then the extra $\mathbf{R}$ is too much.

Comment: Think $x(t)=\hat{x}\exp(\mathrm{i}\omega t)$: The derivative gets an extra factor $\mathrm{i}\omega$, where the $\mathrm{i}$ expresses the phase shift.

Comment: I calculate the displacement in the global reference frame, multiply by omega to get the velocity. I then rotate this back to the local reference frame (as drag coefficients are given in this frame), calculate the force, and then rotate back to the global frame. It may be over complicated! As for the phase shift, we were assuming it's very lightly structurally damped so hopefully the aero force can be assumed to be 180 out from the motion and therefore just be negative.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13544/discussion-between-peter-greaves-and-ccorn)

Comment: OK${{{{{{}}}}}}$

Comment: @ccorn I've been doing a lot more digging on the net about the general approach to solving this problem and it seems that the generally accepted method is to calculate an equivalent viscous damping ratio and not deal with the aerodynamic forces in the force vector. Think I just started going about it in the wrong way!

Comment: It is certainly a good idea to model reaction (damping) forces as such instead of bringing them in as external forces and somehow trying to synchronize them with the actual dynamics. All the best!